# Is there a "do ... until" in Python?

Tags: python, loops

Is there a

```
do until x:
    ...
```

in Python, or a nice way to implement such a looping construct?

Comment: A do-while (although it should be called `until`) is my greatest wish for Python.

Comment: the duplicate did not come up in a search, i think because its title is "do-while"

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I wished that too, until (!) I read the comment found at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/060718.html.

Comment: I'd like to point out that "do while" is distinct from "do until".

Comment: Python is not a free-form language and this kind for statement won't layout nicely with only indentation. You certainly want the condition to appear at the end of the block, otherwise, it's highly ambiguous.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

[There is no do-while loop in Python.](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread39804.html#)

This is a similar construct, taken from the link above.

```
 while True:
     do_something()
     if condition():
        break
```

Comment: BTW, this is called "loop-and-a-half". Python continues to support this construct because it's one of the easiest loop patterns to correctly write and understand. See http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/patterns/plopd/loops.html#loop-and-a-half

Comment: @Brandon Is this any different than: `while !condition do_something()`  ?

Comment: @Bort The loop-and-a-half construct guarantees that `do_something()` will be executed at least once, even if `condition()` is true at the beginning of the loop.  Your `while not condition(): do_something()` construct will never execute `do_something()` if `condition()` evaluates to true at the beginning.

Comment: @brandon yes, the "easy, natural way" is the loop-and-a-half(TM) way, especially because the [just-one-fscking-]until way is so much harder to grasp than "infinite loop with break" ... the truly pythonic, PEP-excreting way. PS: the only reason until isn't in Python is because they found no sane way to incorporate it in the forcefully-indented syntax (at least functional languages compensate this with tail-recursion).

Comment: I would lean towards what @Bort is getting at, and if you want to guarantee a first run then `do_something()` before the while loop. It's not DRY, but I think it's most readable. `do_something() while condition do_something()`. The article posted by @Brandon is calling this a  `sentinel loop`. At the end of the day it's a stylistic choice left to linters, codebase consistency, and/or team choice. Everytime I see a `while True` I fear it never ends, which is why I like to see a condition set with the while line, even if it's not DRY; I don't want to hunt for a break or digest a crazy logic tree

Comment: DRY is not about readbility it's about maintainability.  - repeated code is often more readable than refactored code

Comment: @CTS_AE You may have a false sense of security if you think that `while condition` mean the loop will end. There's no guarantee that `condition` will ever be true. At least with `while True` you know that either A) this loop is meant to run forever, or B) there's a break/return somewhere in the body. You can usually intuit which will be the case based on context.

Answer (score 52):

I prefer to use a looping variable, as it tends to read a bit nicer than just "while 1:", and no ugly-looking `break` statement:

```
finished = False
while not finished:
    ... do something...
    finished = evaluate_end_condition()
```

Comment: I also like this because it is more readable than some of the other alternatives

Answer (score 29):

There's no prepackaged "do-while", but the general Python way to implement peculiar looping constructs is through generators and other iterators, e.g.:

```
import itertools

def dowhile(predicate):
  it = itertools.repeat(None)
  for _ in it:
    yield
    if not predicate(): break
```

so, for example:

```
i=7; j=3
for _ in dowhile(lambda: i<j):
  print i, j
  i+=1; j-=1
```

executes one leg, as desired, even though the predicate's already false at the start.

It's normally better to encapsulate more of the looping logic into your generator (or other iterator) -- for example, if you often have cases where one variable increases, one decreases, and you need a do/while loop comparing them, you could code:

```
def incandec(i, j, delta=1):
  while True:
    yield i, j
    if j <= i: break
    i+=delta; j-=delta
```

which you can use like:

```
for i, j in incandec(i=7, j=3):
  print i, j
```

It's up to you how much loop-related logic you want to put inside your generator (or other iterator) and how much you want to have outside of it (just like for any other use of a function, class, or other mechanism you can use to refactor code out of your main stream of execution), but, generally speaking, I like to see the generator used in a `for` loop that has little (ideally none) "loop control logic" (code related to updating state variables for the next loop leg and/or making tests about whether you should be looping again or not).

Comment: You could use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

Comment: Note that takewhile also consumes the first element in the sequence/generator that does not satisfy the predicate function - that's how it knows to stop taking. But if you then want to iterate over the rest thinking "now I'll get everything where the predicate was False", you'll miss the first item of those.

Answer (score 12):

No there isn't. Instead use a `while` loop such as:

```
while 1:
 ...statements...
  if cond:
    break
```

Comment: Why `while 1`?  What's wrong with `while True`?  Why force a conversion from int to bool?

Comment: @S.Lott, actually, in Python 2.X, True/False are not keywords, they are just built in global constants (that are reassignable like any other variable), so the interpreter has to check what they point to. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3815387/311220

Comment: "the interpreter has to check what they point to"?  What?  Are you claiming this is some kind of useful optimization?  If so, do you have `timeit` benchmarks to substantiate that claim?

Comment: Python 2.7.3
$ python -mtimeit 'while 0:pass'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0132 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit 'while False:pass'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0538 usec per loop

Comment: @yingted "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." -Donald Knuth   Obvious over insignificantly faster, I say.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm just backing up the claim that `0` and `1` are faster than `False` and `True`. For the other 3%, it helps to know that (perhaps counterintuitively) `1` is faster than `True`.

Comment: @yingted I know, but the performance gains are so small that if that kind of time actually matters, you would get much better performance by saving the overhead of using an interpreted language like Python and going with C or C++ or something else native. So I cannot think of a use case when this performance improvement is actually a good idea.

Comment: @jpmc26 I've used Python for programming contests to cut down on development time. Sometimes, in a hard-to-port solution, a tight numerical loop is the bottleneck, and switching ` True` to `1` bumps my solution from "time limit exceeded" to "correct", a tiny ~10%-20% speed increase. Just because you've never needed an optimization doesn't it doesn't have its uses.

Comment: All of this says to me we need better metaprogramming so we can make our own do_while, until, etc wrapped around a block of code.  I can dream of it anyway.

Comment: Just to note, this is no longer true in Python 3, due to the fact that `False` is a keyword now.

Comment: Yes, so just to close out the discussion, python 3.8.2 µbenches: `python -mtimeit "while False: pass;"` 
50000000 loops, best of 5: 8.24 nsec per loop 
`python -mtimeit "while 0: pass;"` 
50000000 loops, best of 5: 8.32 nsec per loop