# boolean operators in PYTHON 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean-logic

I'm writting a piece of program in which I ask for input from user.

I want python to check if the input is digit (not words or puntuation...) and if it is a number indicating an object in my tuple. If one of the 3 conditions result in False then I would like the user to provide another value for that variable. Here's my code

```
colour={'yello':1, 'blue':2, 'red':3, 'black': 4, 'white': 5, 'green': 6}
height_measurements=('centimeter:1', 'inch:2', 'meter:3', 'foot:4')
weight_measurements=('gram:1', 'kilogram:2', 'pounds:3')
print height_measurements
hm_choice = raw_input('choose your height measurement').lower()
while not hm_choice.isdigit() or hm_choice > 0 or hm_choice < len(height_measurements) :
    hm_choice = raw_input('choose your height measurement').lower()        
print weight_measurements
wm_choice = raw_input('choose your weight measurement').lower()
while not wm_choice.isdigit() or wm_choice > 0 or wm_choce < len(weight_measurements) :
    wm_choice = raw_input('choose your weight measurement').lower()
```

When I put this to test, it kept making me insert input for height_measurement constantly no matter what I put in

Please check my code and correct for me. Also if you will, please provide me with better code of yours.

Comment: `not` has higher precedence than `or`. Use parens.

Answer (score 6):

I won't fix your code for you entirely, but I will explain something to you which you seem to be confused about.

`raw_input` returns a string. Strings and integers are two types and cannot be compared to each other (even though in python 2 [this is does not raise](http://codrspace.com/durden/comparing-unrelated-python-types/) a `TypeError`). So your variable `hm_choice` is a string and you're correct to use the `isdigit` method to ensure it is an integer. However, you're then comparing a string to an integer which will always evaluate to True in one of those conditions which means that while loop will never stop. So I pose this question to you: **How do you get an integer from a string?**

Next, you need to examine the logic of that loop. You're saying: While `hm_choice` is not a digit OR while `hm_choice` is greater than 0 (which we already know is an invalid statement) OR while `hm_choice` is less than 4 (or the length of your tuple).

So if any of those are True, then the loop will not end. If you read the article I linked above, you'll figure out which of those always evaluates to True. ;)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I profitted alot from your answer. What you wrote there was just exactly what happened! I now understand why the program kept asking for input. However, I'm still working on the question you posed to me "how to get an integer from a string". I had thought that when user puts in a number then Python shall take that as a numeric object and so provide methods as well as operators that work on number.

Comment: Since you seem stuck, if you look at @jary's answer you'll see that he takes `hm_choice` and calls `int(hm_choice)` assuming `hm_choice` is an integer (you guarantee that by placing `hm_choice.isdigit()` first) it will return an integer for you.

Answer (score 0):

> When I put this to test, it kept making me insert input for
>   height_measurement constantly no matter what I put in

That was because `hm_choice > 0` is comparision between string and int, which is [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) and can equal either `True` or `False` depending on the implementation.

I didn't quite get the meaning of the third condition, so i just placed the `THE_OTHER_CONDITION` there instead. If you define `THE_OTHER_CONDITION = True` the code will work.

```
colour={'yello':1, 'blue':2, 'red':3, 'black': 4, 'white': 5, 'green': 6}
height_measurements=('centimeter:1', 'inch:2', 'meter:3', 'foot:4')
weight_measurements=('gram:1', 'kilogram:2', 'pounds:3')

print height_measurements
while True:
    hm_choice = raw_input('choose your height measurement: ').lower()
    if (hm_choice.isdigit() and int(hm_choice) > 0 and THE_OTHER_CONDITION):
        break

print weight_measurements
while True:
    wm_choice = raw_input('choose your weight measurement: ').lower()
    if (wm_choice.isdigit() and int(hm_choice > 0) and THE_OTHER_CONDITION):
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful to me! However, I haven't known what the "break" code is for. I'm looking it up right now.

Comment: Break jumps out of the infinite while loop. It is classical [pattern to create do-until loop in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1662176/1950100)