# While loop assignment

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, variable-assignment, break

```
# Finicky Counter
# Demonstrates the break and continue statements

count = 0
while True:
  count += 1
  # end loop if count greater than 10
  if count > 10:
   break
  # skip 5
  if count == 5:
    continue
  print(count)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Why does the while True loop apply to count in this circumstance? I dont understand why the boolean is gauging the result of count. Wouldn't the correct syntax be:

```
while count:
```

Any help clarifying this would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply: It isn't. `while True:` loops forever. The `break` is the only thing that will stop that loop.

Comment: Why does it loop forever if the while loop isn't gauging count? What is true then?

Comment: `True` is a boolean value that is built into Python. `while x:` looks at `x` on each iteration, and if `bool(X)` is `True`, then it continues to loop, otherwise it stops. As `x` is `True` here, `bool(True)` is always `True`, and so the loop will never stop (well, except for something else stopping it - an exception or a `break` statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you follow the code step-by-step in a debugger (a simple ide which allows this is PyScripter).

Just a few remarks:

- `while True` is an endless loop. It can only be left by a `break` or `return` statement.
- therefore the loop will run until the condition `count > 10` is met. The break will terminate the loop and the next command (`input ...`) is executed.
- if `count == 5`, `continue` tells python to jump **immediately** to the beginning of the loop without executing the following statement (therefore the "5" ist not printed).

But: follow the code in a debugger!

Answer (score 0):

`count` is 0, so `while count` would never even enter the loop, since 0 is False in a boolean context.

Python doesn't have a construct similar to the `repeat ... until (condition)` found in some other languages. So if you want a loop to always start, but only end when a condition becomes true, the usual way to do it is to set the condition to just `True` - which, obviously, is always true - and then explicitly test the condition inside the loop, and break out using `break`.

To answer your comment, the thing that's true here is simply the value `True`, which as I say will always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a while loop is "while *condition*."  The block beneath the while loop executes until either *condition* evaluates to False or a break command is executed.  "while True" means the condition always is True and the loop won't stop unless a break is execute.  It's a frequent python idiom used since python doesn't have a [do while loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662161/is-there-a-do-until-in-python)